# Manjaro in dual-boot results in "not a valid root device"

Tags: boot, multi-boot, arch-linux, manjaro

I've tried to install Manjaro alongside Windows 10 on my Dell laptop following this guide: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/root-tip-dual-boot-manjaro-and-windows/1164

The manual suggests creating a separate EFI partition as part of Manjaro installation, which I did.
The installation went smoothly but after a reboot I was sent to Windows.

I've done some testing and these are my observations:

- Manjaro is listed as first entry in BIOS boot list
- Using "F12 One-time boot" to start Manjaro shows black screen with options like
  "Press F1 to retry", "Press F2 to config", "Press F3 to run analytic", which send back to BIOS

As a next step I tried to boot Manjaro again from my LiveUSB. From a loaded menu I chose the "Show EFI bootloaders" option, which gave me a list of 6 entries

- (hd1,gpt5)/efi/Manjaro/grubx64.efi
- (hd1,gpt5)/efi/boot/bootx64.efi
- (hd1,gpt1)/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
- (hd1,gpt1)/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
- (hd1,gpt1)/efi/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi
- (hd1,gpt1)/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

The list above confirms that Manjaro has created a separate EFI partition (gpt5) alongside initial Windows EFI partition (gpt1).

When I try to boot Manjaro from that list (first entry) I'm getting a black screen with error: **not a valid root device**.
Next I used the menu edit option "E = Edit Boot Options" to view the entry.

There I saw two parameters being set, **chainloader** with value **(hd1,gpt5)/efi/Manjaro/grubx64.efi** and **root** with value **(hd1,gpt5)**. I've modified root value to **(hd1,gpt1)** and tried to load for that configuration and it **worked!**

I'm not sure though how to make this change persistent, is it part of GRUB configuration or EFI configuration? What exactly is **root** param here and why gpt5 is considered not a valid root device? What should I do?

Thanks!

**SOLVED!**

After launching Manjaro using the edit hack above I installed *gparted* and noticed that my *gpt5* EFI partition was missing **boot** flag (I'm pretty sure I've selected it during installation) and had **legacy_boot** instead. I used *gparted* to change flags of this partition and now everything works

Answer (score -1):

Hello same probleme same sollution
so I tryed from this link
[https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/using-livecd-v17-0-1-and-above-as-grub-to-boot-os-with-broken-bootloader/24916][1]
this Solution to start manjaro
##################### Simple Configfile Method ########################

1. boot up livecd in the right mode, uefi or bios-legacy
2. Do not boot up to live OS, but press ‘c’ at the start menu and we’ll get to the grub    prompt (grub>).
3. To be sure you've started up livecd in the right mode, at grub
   prompt, check output of

   grub> echo $grub_platform

If output is pc , you've booted up in bios-legacy.
If output is efi , you've booted up in uefi.
If you're in the wrong mode, reboot livecd in the right mode.

4. If you are in the right mode, continue.

   grub> search.file /etc/manjaro-release  root

   grub> configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg

   grub> boot //dont executed booted auotomatically

> After launching Manjaro using the edit hack above I installed gparted
> and noticed that my gpt5 EFI partition was missing boot flag (I'm
> pretty sure I've selected it during installation) and had legacy_boot
> instead. I used gparted to change flags of this partition and now
> everything works